# JavaScript map id from one array of object to another

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```js
const rowData = [];
const arr1 = [{
    "bId": "F1.1.4",
    "bName": "Mercedes",
    "cId": "150494",
    "cName": "Benz",
    "flag": "Maintain"
  },
  {
    "bId": "F1.1.4",
    "bName": "Ford",
    "cId": "150744",
    "cName": "Mustang",
    "flag": "Maintain"
  },
  {
    "bId": "F1.1.4",
    "bName": "Volkswagon",
    "cId": "4961",
    "cName": "Polo",
    "flag": "Maintain"
  },
  {
    "bId": "F1.1.5",
    "bName": "Isdera",
    "cId": "N/A",
    "cName": "Isdera",
    "flag": "Test"
  }
]

const arr2 = [{
    "cId": "150494",
    "flag": "Decommission"
  },
  {
    "cId": "150744",
    "flag": "Invest"
  },
  {
    "cId": "4961",
    "flag": "Pending"
  }
]

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  const obj = {
    custId: arr1[i].cId,
    custName: arr1[i].cName,
    bId: arr1[i].bId,
    bufName: arr1[i].bName,
    impFlag: arr2.filter(({cId}) => cId === arr1[i].cId).map(({flag}) => (flag)).toString()
  };
  rowData.push(obj);
}
console.log(rowData)
```

Hi, I'm checking if `cId` in `arr2` is present in `arr1` and based on it I'm updating the flag for which cId is present, but for the remaining values which are not present in arr2, impFlag is coming as `""`. It should remain the same as in arr1. I'm not sure how to add conditions accordingly??

Comment: you don't want impFlag: "" in arr1 if cId is not matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `""` is the only [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value that you'll get from calling [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString), you can use the [`||` (OR)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator to provide a default value when there are no matching flags, eg:

```js
arr2.filter(...).map(...).toString() || arr1[i].flag
```

Above, when `.toString()` results in a falsy `""` value, the right-hand side of the `||` operator is used as the result instead. Note that `.filter()` is good if you have an array of results, which means that there are potentially multiple objects with the same `cId` in `arr2`. If you can only have one object, then `.find()` instead of filter would be more appropriate:

```js
arr2.find(...)?.flag ?? arr1[i].flag
```

```js
const rowData = [];
const arr1 = [{ "bId": "F1.1.4", "bName": "Mercedes", "cId": "150494", "cName": "Benz", "flag": "Maintain" }, { "bId": "F1.1.4", "bName": "Ford", "cId": "150744", "cName": "Mustang", "flag": "Maintain" }, { "bId": "F1.1.4", "bName": "Volkswagon", "cId": "4961", "cName": "Polo", "flag": "Maintain" }, { "bId": "F1.1.5", "bName": "Isdera", "cId": "N/A", "cName": "Isdera", "flag": "Test" } ];
const arr2 = [{ "cId": "150494", "flag": "Decommission" }, { "cId": "150744", "flag": "Invest" }, { "cId": "4961", "flag": "Pending" } ];


for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  const obj = {
    custId: arr1[i].cId,
    custName: arr1[i].cName,
    bId: arr1[i].bId,
    bufName: arr1[i].bName,
    impFlag: arr2.filter(({cId}) => cId === arr1[i].cId).map(({flag}) => (flag)).toString() || arr1[i].flag
  };
  rowData.push(obj);
}
console.log(rowData)
```

---

Personally, I would write this logic as below. As you're performing a mapping operator, `.map()` is a good tool for this:

```js
const arr1 = [{ "bId": "F1.1.4", "bName": "Mercedes", "cId": "150494", "cName": "Benz", "flag": "Maintain" }, { "bId": "F1.1.4", "bName": "Ford", "cId": "150744", "cName": "Mustang", "flag": "Maintain" }, { "bId": "F1.1.4", "bName": "Volkswagon", "cId": "4961", "cName": "Polo", "flag": "Maintain" }, { "bId": "F1.1.5", "bName": "Isdera", "cId": "N/A", "cName": "Isdera", "flag": "Test" } ];
const arr2 = [{ "cId": "150494", "flag": "Decommission" }, { "cId": "150744", "flag": "Invest" }, { "cId": "4961", "flag": "Pending" } ];


const cIdMap = new Map(arr2.map(({cId, flag}) => [cId, flag]));

const rowData = arr1.map((obj) => ({
  custId: obj.cId,
  custName: obj.cName,
  bId: obj.bId,
  bufName: obj.bName,
  impFlag: cIdMap.get(obj.cId) ?? obj.flag
}));

console.log(rowData)
```

Here, the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) creates a structure that maps the cId value to its corresponding flag value (this assumes each cId is unique in `arr2`). This `Map` is then accessed in the `.map()` callback, where we use the [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) to make the current object's flag (`obj.flag`) the default if the Map doesn't contain a cId mapping for the current object.